# Use LaTeX symbols in sympy expressions

Tags: python, latex, sympy

I would like to do some calculations and then have those plotted using sympy. I want to use consistent notation, so I need to define a symbol which will be printed as $\Delta_l^y$.

What I have tried so far:

```
delta__i_0 = sympy.symbols('Delta__i_0')
sympy.pprint(delta__i_0)
```

which works fine.
Unfortunately

```
delta__y_l = sympy.symbols('Delta__y_l')
sympy.pprint(delta__y_l)
```

does not really look nice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the command line Python interpreter, you could use `sympy.printing.latex`. For example,

```
import sympy as sym
import sympy.printing as printing
delta__y_l = sym.symbols('Delta__y_l')
print(printing.latex(delta__y_l))
```

prints

```
\Delta^{y}_{l}
```

---

Or, using IPython notebook, call `sym.init_printing()` to enable pretty-printing:
[image]

Comment: Hmm... does not work for me. The LaTeX output works, but unfortunately not the ipython method. It shows '{Deltasymbol}_l__y'. Using python 3.5.3, ipython 5.1.0, sympy 1.0.

Comment: Wow, now consider that: Your method works in my jupyter notebook, but not in my ipython started from terminal... I guess I should report this as a bug somewhere. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Directly pprint works for a symbol.
But as part of an expression, it is still displayed incorrectly